# List all the members whose name starts with R or G and contains letter I in it

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

List all the members whose name starts with `R` or `G` and contains letter I in it using REGEXP ?

#### Query

```
SELECT *
FROM member
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (member_name, '^[R|G]', 'i')
and REGEXP_LIKE (member_name, 'i', 'i');
```

Can I combine both the `REGEXP_LIKE` expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way is to use `LIKE` to achieve the desired result as below:

```
SELECT 
    name 
FROM myName
WHERE name LIKE '%l%' AND (name LIKE 'r%' OR name LIKE 'g%')
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
SELECT *
FROM   member
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE (member_name, '^[R|G](.+)?i');
```

This will select all member where there name start with R or G followed by any or no
characters and the i.

Answer (score -1):

Try this query in SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM member
where member_name LIKE '[R-G]%'
```

Comment: This will only match `member_name` values literally beginning with "[R-G]"

Comment: Result :  No data found

This is not working even for member_name which starts with R and G

Thank you helping me out